# Rewrite All URLs to Lowercase except any static resource

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So.
I have added the following to my vhost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

And then added the following to my site's .htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Which worked great for making any incoming URL lowercase.

The issue I stumbled into, was any image, js, etc... (static resource) was also attempting to rewrite to all lowercase.   On a Linux box, this simply does not fly when the actual file name is Uppercase.  (no, I have no control over how the files are named...)

How can I force the rewrite to exclude all my static resources?

CentOS 7, Apache 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude static files from rewrite. For images it will look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
```